# Put a space every 5 characters without using regex or StringBuilder

Tags: java, string

I want a user to put in a sentence with the scanner class.
Make sure to filter out all the spaces (for example the sentence: `this is a test` becomes `thisisatest`)
And then print out that sentence with a for loop with a space every 5 characters 
(for example `thisi sates t`).

This is what i have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlockText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give your sentence: ");
        String sentence = s.nextLine();
        String nospace = sentence.replace(" ", "");
        String out = "";       

        for (int i = 5; i < nospace.length(); i+=5) {

            out += nospace.replaceAll( nospace.substring(i) , " ");        
        }   
        System.out.println("Sentence without spaces: " + nospace);
        System.out.println("This gives: " + out);
    }

}
```

but I have the issue that he repeats certain characters and removes others.
Like you can see underneath after "this gives:"

```
run:
Give your sentence: 
this is a test
Sentence without spaces: thisisatest
This gives: thisi  hisisa es 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Can someone help me out? Like I said in the `titel`, I want to accomplish this with a for loop and without using regex or StringBuilder.

Comment: `replaceAll` uses *regex*. Maybe you meant `replace`.

Comment: @Pshemo well replace or if there is another way to put a space every 5 characters.

Comment: Also `out += nospace...` internally uses `StringBuilder` but in very inefficient way. IMO point of this task is to create `char[]` array with proper size (you can calculate how many additional spaces you will need based on amount of non-space characters) and fill it with characters accordingly. Then you can use `new String(charArray)` to create resulting `String`.

Comment: What should happen for an input that's 5 characters long? Like "hello". Should the output be "hello " (with a trailing space), or just "hello"? (no trialing space)

Comment: It is for a school assignment and we are not allowed yet to use arrays.

Comment: @janos Well if it is exactly 5 characters long then it doesn't really matter that it has a space or has no space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use a `StringBuilder` here, because appending strings with `+=` in a loop is very inefficient.

Without a string builder, you can do something like this:

```
private static String addSpacesEvery5(String s) {
    String out = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) {
            out += " "; // this will run once every five iterations, except the first one
        }
        out += s.charAt(i);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Or more efficiently without `+=`:

```
private static String addSpacesEvery5(String s) {
    // s.length() / 5 is how many spaces we will add
    char[] charArray = new char[s.length() + s.length() / 5];
    int currentPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) {
            charArray[currentPos] = ' ';
            currentPos++;
        }
        charArray[currentPos] = s.charAt(i);
        currentPos++;
    }
    return new String(charArray);
}
```

And then you can use it in your `main` method like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give your sentence: ");
String sentence = s.nextLine();
String nospace = sentence.replace(" ", "");
String out = addSpacesEvery5(nospace);
System.out.println("Sentence without spaces: " + nospace);
System.out.println("This gives: " + out);
```

With a string builder, the `addSpacesEvery5` could be rewritten as:

```
private static String addSpacesEvery5(String s) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) {
            out.append(" ");
        }
        out.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me alot, this is what i needed.

Comment: i did just now, thank you for telling me, i am still a beginner on this website.

Comment: "without a string builder" `out += foo;` is going to be compiled to `out = new StringBuilder(out).append(foo).toString();` (or something similar) anyway, so it's not really avoiding `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one relatively simple and faster:

```
      String tmp = new String();

      int len = str.length();

      int remOdds = len % 5;

      int i = 0;

      while (i < len - remOdds)
      {
         tmp = tmp.concat(str.substring(i, i + 5));
         i += 5;
         if (i < len)
         {
            tmp += " ";
         }
      }

      while (i < len)
      {
         tmp += str.charAt(i);
         i++;
      }

      str = tmp;
```